# Terrence Tao's (or maybe Sarnak's) definition of the topological entropy of a sequence

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, entropy

The following is taken from [a post by Terrence Tao on the Chowla conjecture and the Sarnak conjecture](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/the-chowla-conjecture-and-the-sarnak-conjecture/)
:

> Given a bounded sequence ${f: {\bf N} \rightarrow {\bf C}}$, define the topological entropy of the sequence to be the least exponent ${\sigma}$ with the property that for any fixed ${\varepsilon > 0}$, and for ${m}$ going to infinity the set ${\{ (f(n+1),\ldots,f(n+m)): n \in {\bf N} \} \subset {\bf C}^m}$ of ${f}$ can be covered by ${O( \exp( \sigma m + o(m) ) )}$ balls of radius ${\varepsilon}$ (in the ${\ell^\infty}$ metric). (If ${f}$ arises from a minimal topological dynamical system ${(X,T)}$ by ${f(n) := F(T^n x)}$ and ${X}$ is generated by ${F}$ and its shifts, the above notion is equivalent to the usual notion of the topological entropy of a dynamical system.

But I have difficulty understanding why his (or maybe Sarnak's) definition of the topological entropy of a sequence can be identified with the usual notion of the topological entropy of a dynamical system:

Specifically, I would like to ask:

(1) What is the meaning of "If ${f}$ arises from a minimal topological dynamical system ${(X,T)}$ by ${f(n) := F(T^n x)}$ and ${X}$ is generated by ${F}$ and its shifts"? In particular, what is the meaning of "minimal" and “${X}$ is generated by ${F}$ and its shifts"? (I really want to know if $X$ is necessarily a compact metric space)

(2) Once (1) is clarified, I hope it is not hard to show that "the above notion is equivalent to the usual notion of the topological entropy of a dynamical system" (but let me know if it is not so obvious). Is "topological entropy of a dynamical system" he meant simply the situation of compact metric space, where [topological entropy can be relatively easily defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4362913/direct-proof-for-any-homeomorphism-on-0-1-having-zero-entropy)? Or topological entropy for general non-metrizable spaces?

My question is mainly about the clarification in (1), once (1) is clear, I think (2) shouldn't be hard.

Comment: What is $F{}{}$?

Comment: @markvs I guess it is some function induced from $f$ (to be determined by us), but I can't think of any good examples to have a better understanding of it... may be you can take a look at Tao's post above or other posts to say something more :p?

Comment: The notion of topological entropy (of a sequence) goes back to Kolmogorov, much earlier than Tao or Sarnak, file:///C:/Users/sapirmv/Google%20Drive/book/3800/tse.pdf

Comment: @markvs I know, but what about the "topological entropy of a sequence" introduced above? Had Kolmogorow also studied this particular situation of topological entropy?

Comment: I do not know. It is supposed to be a simple particular case. You should ask Tao.

Comment: @markvs I wish I could, but he might be too busy to answer such elementary questions...

Comment: As far as I know he answers such questions, especially when his text is involved. His blog has many similar questions (all answered).

Comment: Minimal system is one with all orbits dense.